# Overriding udisks2 /media/$USER/mount with custom fixed mount point for specific volume, under Debian Buster

Tags: debian, systemd, udev, automounting, udisks

I am using *Debian Buster*, 10.7, and I am relatively new to udev/udisks2/systemd and have been making a effort to get to know them better and have learned quite a lot, though I cannot seem to figure out how to both prevent udisks2 from auto mounting a particular volume (an SD card) as `/media/$USER/foo`, as well as mount it instead as `/data`.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
$ grep /data /etc/fstab
UUID="3537-3761"      /data     exfat-fuse    defaults,nofail,x-systemd.device-timeout=2ms  0       0

$ cat /etc/systemd/system/data-sdcard-mount.service   
[Unit]
Description=Mount Data SD Card on /data
[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStart=/bin/mount /data
ExecStop=/bin/umount /data

$ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/99-data-sdcard.rules
ACTION=="add", \
    SUBSYSTEM=="block", \
    ENV{DEVTYPE}=="partition", \
    ENV{ID_DRIVE_MEDIA_FLASH_SD}=="1", \
    ENV{ID_NAME}=="SF256", \
    ENV{ID_SERIAL}=="0x3db0a775", \
    RUN+="/bin/systemctl start data-sdcard-mount", \
    ENV{UDISKS_IGNORE}="1", \
    OPTIONS="last_rule"

ACTION=="remove", \
    SUBSYSTEM=="block", \
    ENV{DEVTYPE}=="partition", \
    ENV{ID_DRIVE_MEDIA_FLASH_SD}=="1", \
    ENV{ID_NAME}=="SF256", \
    ENV{ID_SERIAL}=="0x3db0a775", \
    RUN+="/bin/systemctl stop data-sdcard-mount", \
    OPTIONS="last_rule"
```

Here is what I see syslog in another terminal window, when the card is inserted (though after logging in to MATE):

```
Feb  4 13:25:51 localhost kernel: [508706.027711] mmc3: new high speed SDXC card at address aaaa
Feb  4 13:25:51 localhost kernel: [508706.044472] mmcblk3: mmc3:aaaa SF256 238 GiB 
Feb  4 13:25:51 localhost kernel: [508706.058372]  mmcblk3: p1
Feb  4 13:25:51 localhost systemd[1]: Starting Mount Data SD Card on /data...
Feb  4 13:25:51 localhost mount[1734]: FUSE exfat 1.3.0
Feb  4 13:25:51 localhost mount[1734]: WARN: volume was not unmounted cleanly.
Feb  4 13:25:51 localhost mount.exfat-fuse: volume was not unmounted cleanly
Feb  4 13:25:51 localhost systemd[1]: data.mount: Unit is bound to inactive unit dev-disk-by\x2duuid-3537\x2d3761.device. Stopping, too.
Feb  4 13:25:51 localhost systemd[1]: Started Mount Data SD Card on /data.
Feb  4 13:25:51 localhost systemd[1]: Unmounting /data...
Feb  4 13:25:51 localhost systemd[14720]: data.mount: Succeeded.
Feb  4 13:25:51 localhost systemd[2920]: data.mount: Succeeded.
Feb  4 13:25:51 localhost systemd[1]: data.mount: Succeeded.
Feb  4 13:25:51 localhost systemd[1]: Unmounted /data.
Feb  4 13:25:52 localhost systemd[1]: Started Clean the /media/vanfan/Data mount point.
Feb  4 13:25:52 localhost udisksd[2010]: Mounted /dev/mmcblk3p1 at /media/vanfan/Data on behalf of uid 1000
```

It looks like it mounts to /data but gets unmounted for some reason.

Here is the out of `udisksctl info -b /dev/mmcblk3p1`:

```
$ udisksctl info -b /dev/mmcblk3p1
/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/mmcblk3p1:
  org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Block:
    Configuration:              []
    CryptoBackingDevice:        '/'
    Device:                     /dev/mmcblk3p1
    DeviceNumber:               45825
    Drive:                      '/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/drives/SF256_0x3db0a775'
    HintAuto:                   true
    HintIconName:               
    HintIgnore:                 false
    HintName:                   
    HintPartitionable:          true
    HintSymbolicIconName:       
    HintSystem:                 false
    Id:                         by-uuid-3537-3761
    IdLabel:                    Data
    IdType:                     exfat
    IdUUID:                     3537-3761
    IdUsage:                    filesystem
    IdVersion:                  1.0
    MDRaid:                     '/'
    MDRaidMember:               '/'
    PreferredDevice:            /dev/mmcblk3p1
    ReadOnly:                   false
    Size:                       255835766784
    Symlinks:                   /dev/disk/by-id/mmc-SF256_0x3db0a775-part1
                                /dev/disk/by-label/Data
                                /dev/disk/by-path/platform-4809c000.mmc-part1
                                /dev/disk/by-uuid/3537-3761
    UserspaceMountOptions:      uhelper=udisks2
  org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Filesystem:
    MountPoints:        /media/vanfan/Data
    Size:               0
  org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Partition:
    Flags:              0
    IsContained:        false
    IsContainer:        false
    Name:               
    Number:             1
    Offset:             33554432
    Size:               255835766784
    Table:              '/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/mmcblk3'
    Type:               0x07
    UUID:
```

Might I be missing something? Is there a better approach to this? I have tried to research this topic before and while trying to get this to work, and I really do't understand why this isn't working.

Comment: If you have an entry in `fstab` (which you have), UDisks should honor it and mount the device to `/data`, if it isn't doing that, it's a bug in UDisks and I recommend to [report it](https://github.com/storaged-project/udisks/issues). Are yiu sure the UUID in `fstab` is correct? Can you add output of `udisksctl info -b /dev/mmcblk3p1` to your question?

Comment: @VojtechTrefny, thanks, I have added the output of `udisksctl info -b /dev/mmcblk3p1` to my question as requested.

Comment: @VojtechTrefny I have made another update. Right after posting that output, I was looking at the post and noticed a typo I had made in the udev rule `RUN+=` where I had `stop` instead of `start`, and after that it mounts to `/media/vanfan/Data` instead of `/data` so something is still not right.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I found why is UDisks ignoring your `fstab` entry -- UDisks can't parse your `fstab`:

```
UUID="3537-3761"      /data     exfat-fuse    defaults,nofail,x-systemd.device-timeout=2ms  0       0
```

The quotation marks in the `UUID="3537-3761"` are causing the problem. Quick test on my system:

With quotation marks:

```
$ udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdb1
Mounted /dev/sdb1 at /run/media/vojta/E2FC-EAE3
```

Without:

```
$ udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdb1
Mounted /dev/sdb1 at /mnt/test
```

I'm not sure if this is supposed to be working, all examples (including `man fstab`) say to specify entries with UUID as `UUID=<uuid>` so without the quotation marks, but `mount` does work so UDisks probably should too so you might consider reporting this as a UDisks bug.

Comment: Thanks, after removing the quotes from the UUID in `fstab` and reinserting, it no longer mounts to `/media/vanfan/...`, it doesn't mount at all. I can do `sudo udisksctl mount -b /dev/mmcblk3p1` and then it mouns to `/data`. Any idea why it isn't mounting automatically? I have also tried adding `auto` to the fstab options `defaults,auto,nofail,x-systemd.device-timeout=2ms`.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I had disabled the `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-data-sdcard.rules` udev rule (I commented everything in it and renamed it to `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-data-sdcard.rules.disabled`)

Comment: Problem with UDisks and automounting is that UDisks actually doesn't do the "automount" part, it only sets the `HintAuto` property (which in your case is correctly set to `true`) and the "upper" layer (GVFs in GNOME) decides if it wants to mount the device immediately or wait for user to click the icon.